# XORing hex numbers

Tags: python-3.x, bitwise-xor

I want to apply bitwise XOR operation on two hex numbers but my code seems to not working because of "F" in number. I tried converting into int before applying xor but still getting the error.

```
i = b"77"
res = operator.xor(int(i),int(b"FFFF"))
print(res)
```

Bit I am getting the following error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'FFFF'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell `int` that the strings you're given it are in hexadecimal, so it tried to parse them in decimal. Pass `16` as the second parameter to it.